# Azure Monitor (Log Analytics) query limitation 10,000, not able to see anywhere we can configure

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

If there any way we can increase the page (any query in Log Analytics) from 10,000 to more than this value? its default page 10,000. I tried to understand in this link but not really getting how we can increase this count

Comment: I believe you forgot to mention the link.

Comment: I believe you won't be able to increase the count, you'll need to work with paging

Answer (score 0):

service limits for Log Analytics are mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/service-limits.

according to the documentation, you can run the query programmatically, if you need to have it return more than 10,000 records.

[image]

and:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Yoni. I was not able to see this option in azure, could you please help me with that too?